# An error occurred while installing actionpack (5.0.2), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal, actionpack

I get a error when I execute `rails new myprojectname`:

> Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out -
>   SSL_connect (https://rubygems.org/gems/actionpack-5.0.2.gem)
>   An error occurred while installing actionpack (5.0.2), and Bundler
>   cannot continue.
>   Make sure that `gem install actionpack -v '5.0.2'` succeeds before bundling.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error information points out:

> Make sure that gem install actionpack -v '5.0.2' succeeds before bundling.

So, in your terminal you should execute the:

```
$ gem install actionpack -v '5.0.2'
```

Then you `rails new your project name` again. and overwrite the conflict place.